# NEXT.JS 14 Root layout Removal

Tags: next.js14

I'm learning NEXT.JS 14 and it has a layout.js file which wraps the entire app with specific styling. The issue I'm facing is that I'm unable to remove specific layout.js styles in particular pages. Even if I declare another layout.js in the route folder I would still get the root layout.js styles. I want to remove the root layout.js in the page

Answer (score 0):

The app/layout.js file (root layout) is required and cannot be removed.  It would help to see a visual of your project structure and the code for any files in question.  At the time of my answer, I am not allowed to comment, and there is not much detail given to firmly understand your situation.  Only what is shared across all routes should be specified in the root layout, including styling.  At the minimum, the root layout file must have `<html>` and `<body>` element tags.  If you have any additional element tags in your root layout file (such as `<header>` or `<footer>`, you could extract these out as separate components and style them separately.  Any HTML not shared across every route should not be placed in the root layout.

I believe you are stating that you tried adding a sibling layout.js for each route.  If you did, you can add styling within that route (folder) for the elements in question.  CSS Modules makes this especially easy.

Answer (score 0):

For your question simplest answer is you can't remove the RootLayout as it define the global structure of your application HTML and it wraps your components.
For your requirement what you can do is remove the global.css from your RootLayout and

1. You can add your own layout file to a component directory or add to the root level of your custom component.
2. Check the route and exclude using the Layout for the specific file you want to avoid (This way you can use the global styles and omit global style for the specific routes).